# Adding a scroll bar to continuously scrolling carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I currently have a image scroller using continuously scrolling carousel with stop on `MouseOver` similar to the one fitbit has, first thing on their jobs page:

http://www.fitbit.com/jobs

Except I don't know how to add the scrollbar where it comes out the other way if you scroll it to the end of one side.

This is my code at the moment, its really simple:

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="carousel">
        <div>
            <img src="img/fruit1.png" alt="fruit1" width="200" height="200" />
            <span>Apple</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="img/fruit2.png" alt="fruit2" width="200" height="200" />
            <span>Mandarin</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="img/fruit3.png" alt="fruit3" width="200" height="200" />
            <span>Banannas</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="img/fruit4.png" alt="fruit4" width="200" height="200" />
            <span>Cherries</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="img/fruit5.png" alt="fruit5" width="200" height="200" />
            <span>Orange</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="img/fruit6.png" alt="fruit6" width="200" height="200" />
            <span>Melon</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="img/fruit7.png" alt="fruit7" width="200" height="200" />
            <span>Lemon</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="img/fruit8.png" alt="fruit8" width="200" height="200" />
            <span>Grapes</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="img/fruit9.png" alt="fruit9" width="200" height="200" />
            <span>Peach</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="img/fruit10.png" alt="fruit10" width="200" height="200" />
            <span>Pear</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="img/fruit11.png" alt="fruit11" width="200" height="200" />
            <span>Strawberry</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="img/fruit12.png" alt="fruit12" width="200" height="200" />
            <span>Melon</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {

    var $c = $('#carousel'),
        $w = $(window);

    $c.carouFredSel({
        align: false,
        items: 10,
        scroll: {
            items: 1,
            duration: 2000,
            timeoutDuration: 0,
            easing: 'linear',
            pauseOnHover: 'immediate'
        }
    });


    $w.bind('resize.example', function() {
        var nw = $w.width();
        if (nw < 990) {
            nw = 990;
        }

        $c.width(nw * 3);
        $c.parent().width(nw);

    }).trigger('resize.example');

});
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
body {
    background-color: #eee;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 300px;
}
body * {
    font-family: Arial, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #333;
    line-height: 22px;
}

#wrapper {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    margin-top: -1px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
}
#carousel {
    margin-top: -100px;
}
#carousel div {
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
    height: 250px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
#carousel div img {
    border: none;
}
#carousel div span {
    display: none;
}
#carousel div:hover span {
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Arial, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 22px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 2px 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 -50px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 50%;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

Using this library extension:

```
jquery.carouFredSel-6.0.4-packed.js
```